# How can I get fuzzy results sorted by relevance using ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Baiscally if I search for something like

```
neckla
```

I want to get results for necklace. When i did a fuzzy search, I got results for food and others (basically it wasn't filtering properly) although the necklace result was there.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you add more requirements. Have you looked at prefix queries?

Answer (score 0):

Have you adjusted the min_similarity parameter in your fuzzy query? Increasing the min_similarity may filter out the food and only return the necklace.

```
{
    "fuzzy" : { 
        "jewelry" : {
            "value" : "neckla",
            "boost" : 1.0,
            "min_similarity" : 0.8,
            "prefix_length" : 0
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690127/how-can-i-get-results-that-dont-fully-match-using-elasticsearch), an edgeNGram filter may be your best bet here.